# share webview cookie with phonegap local resource

Tags: security, cookies, cordova, webview

I am trying to migrate some part of the existing web application to phonegap based mobile app. The web application follows the session based authentication and generates required cookies after login.

Now I am doing login via WebView in android and once the cookies are generated I move the activity to phonegap and load the local html file. The local html file then does call the AJAX function to the same domain but it fails as the tokens are not available in cookie.

Is it possible to do??